# SurrealDB: The request needs to adhere to certain constraints

Tags: surrealdb

I just tried to run the first query from the SurrealDB [documentation](https://surrealdb.com/docs/start).

```bash
DATA="INFO FOR DB;"
curl --request POST \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --user "root:root" \
    --data "${DATA}" \
    http://localhost:8000/sql
```

This leads to the following error:

```json
{
  "code": 415,
  "details": "Unsupported media type",
  "description": "The request needs to adhere to certain constraints. Refer to the documentation for supported content types."
}
```

Why doesn't the query in the docs work?

Answer (score 9):

The `Content-Type: application/json` is **not needed** anymore.

You need to replace it with `Accept: application/json`.

```bash
DATA="INFO FOR DB;"
curl --request POST \
    --header "Accept: application/json" \
    --user "root:root" \
    --data "${DATA}" \
    http://localhost:8000/sql
```

There was an [issue](https://github.com/surrealdb/surrealdb/issues/1292) on Github about this.

> In 1.0.0-beta.7 the server required (incorrectly) the Content-Type header to be set, but this was changed to Accept in 1.0.0-beta.8.